# How to darken an html element background while preventing edges from standing out

Tags: css

I'm wondering if it's possible to darken a div while blending all edges.

The example below is an attempt but I can only get the top and bottom edges to blend. Is there some solution where you can also hide left and right edges of the container? Adding a second horizontal linear gradient doesn't seem to work and neither does a radial gradient.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.block {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.01), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 20%,
  rgba(0,0,0,.4) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.2) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,.01) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: There is no CSS square gradient available yet, so the second best option is most likely box-shadow, would this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/4xLamxxp/3/

Comment: @LGSon That looks so close. If only there was a way to hide the crisp edges and blend them instead.

Comment: You can increase the shadow and decrease the element  https://jsfiddle.net/4xLamxxp/4/ ... or like this, with an opacity on the shadow/background https://jsfiddle.net/4xLamxxp/5/

Comment: @LGSon The first link looks great, thanks! Never thought you could set the height: 0 like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can help you.

First, I will provide you some code that works and then I'll explain WHY it works. Here goes:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class='block'>
        <div class='block2'>
           Hello World
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: grey;
}

.block {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.01), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 20%,
  rgba(0,0,0,.4) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.2) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,.01) 100%);
}

.block2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Ok, allow me to explain! :)

Let's look at your HTML first. You are basically containing the "Hello World" text and so whatever background you have there will be bound by the borders of that container.

So, if you want to have your gradient have no side borders, then have that container (that div) extend the full width of the page. You can still keep the text in its own container and, as long as you don't give it any background color settings, it will be TRANSPARENT....ooooo...ahhhh!  LOL!!!

You will notice that in the HTML, all I did was put a div inside your original "block" class div and I called it "block2". The "block2" div I created is where I put the text.

Ok, now let's talk about the CSS code.

There are 3 changes I made, and the are VERY simple. Here they are in order:

**Change 1** - In the very first line of code I put:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

That was just to make it so that you didn't have any weird spaces at the outside edges of your monitor, or anybody else's monitor for that matter. it is a very useful little snippet of code and it's a "soft browser reset". It just gives you a level playing field by resetting those values to nothing, so that you will have a better chance of having your creation look consistent on different browsers.

**Change 2** - I added the following code in your original CSS code:

```
.block {
  width: 100%;
}
```

All that did was extend that div to the width of the browser, which of course got rid of the borders at the sides. Instead of a definite width of 400px, we told the browser to take it the full width of the screen.

**Change 3** - I added a little styling to the new div I created called "block2". Here is the code:

```
.block2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

I just gave it the same measurements that you had originally and then centered it in the middle of the "block" div (and thereby the screen because the div's width is now 100%), by giving it a margin of auto.

I hope that helps. Sorry the explanation was so long! I just like being thorough and I like to help people understand why a solution works the way it does.

:)

Comment: I think my only option is to extend the element the entire width like you are showing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy, but you could try to adjust a radial gradient ([Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)):

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.block {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 3em;
  width: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,1) 41%,rgba(7,7,7,1) 42%,rgba(229,229,229,0) 75%);
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  Hello World
</div>
```